# Retrofit 2 NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, retrofit, butterknife

Выдаёт вот такое `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'by.homemadeapps.weatherapp.DataModel.Entity.Main by.homemadeapps.weatherapp.DataModel.Entity.ResponseData.getMain()' on a null object reference`

Вроде всё по мануалу, создал интерфес

```
public interface WeatherAPI {
    @GET("/data/2.5/weather&appid=" + Constants.HTTP.API_KEY)
    Call<ResponseData> getWeather(@Query("q") String city);
}
```

Сервис:

```
public class WeatherService {
    private WeatherAPI service;
     public WeatherService() {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://api.openweathermap.org")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        service = retrofit.create(WeatherAPI.class);
    }
    public void getWeather(String name, Callback callback) throws IOException {
        service.getWeather(name).enqueue(callback);
    }
 }
```

mainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @BindView(R.id.CITY_NAME_FIND)
    EditText mEnterCityName;
    @BindView(R.id.recyclerView)
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    @BindView(R.id.CityName)
    TextView mCityTextView;
    @BindView(R.id.Speed)
    TextView mSpeedView;
    @BindView(R.id.Humidity)
    TextView mHumidityView;
    @BindView(R.id.CurrentDate)
    TextView mCurrentDateView;
    @BindView(R.id.refresh_button)
    Button mRefreshButton;

    private  WeatherService weatherService;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        weatherService = new WeatherService();
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.refresh_button)
    void onClick() {
        Log.d("working", "fine");

        try {
            weatherService.getWeather("Hrodna", new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) {
                    ResponseData responseData = (ResponseData)response.body();
                    mHumidityView.setText(responseData.getMain().getHumidity());
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


package by.homemadeapps.weatherapp.DataModel.Entity;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.Generated;

@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
public class ResponseData {

    @SerializedName("coord")
    @Expose
    private Coord coord;
    @SerializedName("weather")
    @Expose
    private List<Weather> weather = new ArrayList<Weather>();
    @SerializedName("base")
    @Expose
    private String base;
    @SerializedName("main")
    @Expose
    private Main main;
    @SerializedName("wind")
    @Expose
    private Wind wind;
    @SerializedName("rain")
    @Expose
    private Rain rain;
    @SerializedName("clouds")
    @Expose
    private Clouds clouds;
    @SerializedName("dt")
    @Expose
    private Integer dt;
    @SerializedName("sys")
    @Expose
    private Sys sys;
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Integer id;
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("cod")
    @Expose
    private Integer cod;

    /**
     * @return The coord
     */
    public Coord getCoord() {
        return coord;
    }

    /**
     * @param coord The coord
     */
    public void setCoord(Coord coord) {
        this.coord = coord;
    }

    /**
     * @return The weather
     */
    public List<Weather> getWeather() {
        return weather;
    }

    /**
     * @param weather The weather
     */
    public void setWeather(List<Weather> weather) {
        this.weather = weather;
    }

    /**
     * @return The base
     */
    public String getBase() {
        return base;
    }

    /**
     * @param base The base
     */
    public void setBase(String base) {
        this.base = base;
    }

    /**
     * @return The main
     */
    public Main getMain() {
        return main;
    }

    /**
     * @param main The main
     */
    public void setMain(Main main) {
        this.main = main;
    }

    /**
     * @return The wind
     */
    public Wind getWind() {
        return wind;
    }

    /**
     * @param wind The wind
     */
    public void setWind(Wind wind) {
        this.wind = wind;
    }

    /**
     * @return The rain
     */
    public Rain getRain() {
        return rain;
    }

    /**
     * @param rain The rain
     */
    public void setRain(Rain rain) {
        this.rain = rain;
    }

    /**
     * @return The clouds
     */
    public Clouds getClouds() {
        return clouds;
    }

    /**
     * @param clouds The clouds
     */
    public void setClouds(Clouds clouds) {
        this.clouds = clouds;
    }

    /**
     * @return The dt
     */
    public Integer getDt() {
        return dt;
    }

    /**
     * @param dt The dt
     */
    public void setDt(Integer dt) {
        this.dt = dt;
    }

    /**
     * @return The sys
     */
    public Sys getSys() {
        return sys;
    }

    /**
     * @param sys The sys
     */
    public void setSys(Sys sys) {
        this.sys = sys;
    }

    /**
     * @return The id
     */
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * @param id The id
     */
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     * @return The name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * @param name The name
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * @return The cod
     */
    public Integer getCod() {
        return cod;
    }

    /**
     * @param cod The cod
     */
    public void setCod(Integer cod) {
        this.cod = cod;
    }
 }
```

Что я сделал не так?

**UPD** Не так сделал

```
 public interface WeatherAPI {
    @GET("/data/2.5/weather&appid=" + Constants.HTTP.API_KEY)
    Call<ResponseData> getWeather(@Query("q") String city);
}
```

Должно быть вот так:

```
@GET("/data/2.5/weather")
    Call<ResponseData> getWeather(@Query("q") String city, @Query("APPID")String key);
```

и при таком раскладе ошибок `NullPointerException` удалось избежать, но теперь получив `response` сразу идет в `onFailure()`
Почему, кто знает?

Comment: для начала проверьте, что вам приходит в `Response response`, действительно ли там `ResponseData`

Comment: @metalurgus а как проверить, не подскажете? туплю...

Comment: через отладчик поставьте breakpoint, и посмотрите значение переменной

Comment: @metalurgus в `response` приходит `null`, значит ошибка в запросе?

Comment: для меня сложно так сходу сказать, где именно. Я вообще Retrofit не пользуюсь. ПРосто по логике сказал, где может быть конечная ошибка. Причину этой ошибки я, к сожалению, быстро не найду, а на *долго* у меня нет времени

Answer (score 1):

Оказалось проблема **номер 2** была из-за того что [JSONschemaToPOJO](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) сгенерил немного неправильную модель и там где в JSON приходили `Double`, у меня в модели были `Integer`

Проблема **номер 1** решилась с помощью @metalurgus, который рекомендовал копать что приходит в `response`